# Adding .toggle() to a jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I started by trying to add a `.toggle()` to this code so that the menu will animate on click but also close on a click, then realized that I can't use the `.animate` within a `.toggle()` very well so i'm trying out `.click()`

If there is a way to replace my `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` functions with a click that is what I am looking for.

I've searched but I can't find anywhere this has been done with an animated menu so, here is the javascript for the function:

```
$('#sdt_menu > li').bind('mouseenter',function(){
    var $elem = $(this);
    $elem.find('img')
         .stop(true)
         .animate({
            border: '5px solid #000',

            'width':'150px',
            'height':'170px',
            'left':'0px'
         },400,'easeOutBack')
         .andSelf()
         .find('.sdt_wrap')
         .stop(true)
         .animate({'top':'140px'},500,'easeOutBack')
         .andSelf()
         .find('.sdt_active')
         .stop(true)
         .animate({'height':'170px'},300,function(){
        var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
        if($sub_menu.length){
            var left = '170px';
            if($elem.parent().children().length == $elem.index()+1)
                left = '-170px';
            $sub_menu.show().animate({'left':left},200);
        }    
    });
}).bind('mouseleave',function(){
    var $elem = $(this);
    var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
    if($sub_menu.length)
        $sub_menu.hide().css('left','0px');

    $elem.find('.sdt_active')
         .stop(true)
         .animate({'height':'0px'},300)

         .andSelf().find('img')
         .stop(true)
         .animate({
            border: "2px solid #FFFFFF",
            'width':'150px',
            'height':'150px',
            'left':'0px'},400)
         .andSelf()
         .find('.sdt_wrap')
         .stop(true)
         .animate({'top':'25px'},500);
});
```

Comment: the menu animates and closes on mouseover and mouseleave, im trying to change it to clicks and I can't replace both mouseover and mouseleave with just click

Comment: Have you tried providing your two functions as arguments to `toggle`, i.e., `$("#sdt_menu > li").toggle(function(){...}, function(){...})`?

Comment: @apsillers Where is that in the documentation? Interesting.

Comment: @iambriansreen http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ (it's a bit confusing because there's another jQuery doc page for a [different form of `toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) which comes up first on a Google search)

Comment: @apsillers I knew of toggle - api.jquery.com/toggle but not the other one. Super useful, it lets you stack as many events as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Below I add a class if it opens, and remove a class if it closes which tells the onclick event what to do.</s>

Check out http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/. Simple enough.

Credit to [apsillers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/710446/apsillers).

```
$('#sdt_menu > li').toggle(function(){
    var $elem = $(this);
    var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
    $elem.find('img')
         .stop(true)
         .animate({
            border: '5px solid #000',

            'width':'150px',
            'height':'170px',
            'left':'0px'
         },400,'easeOutBack')
         .andSelf()
         .find('.sdt_wrap')
         .stop(true)
         .animate({'top':'140px'},500,'easeOutBack')
         .andSelf()
         .find('.sdt_active')
         .stop(true)
         .animate({'height':'170px'},300,function(){
        if($sub_menu.length){
            var left = '170px';
            if($elem.parent().children().length == $elem.index()+1)
                left = '-170px';
            $sub_menu.show().animate({'left':left},200);
        }    
    });
}, function(){      
    var $elem = $(this);
    var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
    if($sub_menu.length)
        $sub_menu.hide().css('left','0px');     
    $elem.find('.sdt_active')
         .stop(true)
         .animate({'height':'0px'},300)     
         .andSelf().find('img')
         .stop(true)
         .animate({
            border: "2px solid #FFFFFF",
            'width':'150px',
            'height':'150px',
            'left':'0px'},400)
         .andSelf()
         .find('.sdt_wrap')
         .stop(true)
         .animate({'top':'25px'},500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define a global variable like `var isOpen = true;` then change your code for click

```
$('#sdt_menu > li').on('click', isOpen, function() {
    if (isOpen) {
        // Close
    } else {
        // Open
    }
    isOpen = !isOpen;
});
```

Comment: An extra way to play around with that works too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var isOpen = true;
 $('#sdt_menu > li').click(function(){
       if(isOpen ==  true){
           $(this).hide();
           isOpen = false;
       }else{
           $(this).show();
           isOpen = true;
       }
    }
```

You can set default value of isOpen variable as per your requirement.

.show() and .hide is expanded function of toggle function.